# Watson speech to text

Tags: node.js, twilio, ibm-watson

I am looking for example code on how to call Watson's speech to text function from node.js while using the Twilio platform.

I've been able to utilize the add-on settings in Twilio to call back to my own function when using dial verbs and recording verbs.  That said, this seems to be an all-or-nothing proposition; meaning that ALL dial verbs recordings are transcribed.

While functional, I have several use cases where I record but do not want to transcribe.  As far as I can tell, the best methodology would be to call Watson on an ad-hoc basis from within code as opposed to all the time as defined by settings.

Does documentation exist somewhere that demonstrates how to call Watson speech-to-text given a specified url that contains the recording (RecordingURL)?

Comment: Have you checked the [Watson Speech To Text API documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/node.html?node#recognize)? It has examples in Node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is an undocumented feature in the Speech to Text API that allows you to pass in an `audio_url` parameter, which should perform the task you are looking for.

Unfortunately, the Watson Node SDK does not yet support that parameter, so you will need to create your own request using a package like [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) or [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).